# Using lambda and closure together in PHP

Tags: php, lambda, closures

I am trying to understand the use of these two lambda and closure function. But can't understand it properly. It would be great if i could understand it with illustration and details.

```
 $array = array(12345, 'abcde');
 $lambda = function($value) { return md5($value); };
 $closure = function($value) use ($lambda) {
 return 'MD5 Hash: ' . $lambda($value);//what is $lambda($value) here?
 };
 $result = array_map($closure, $array);


var_dump($result);
//array (size=2)
//0 => string 'MD5 Hash: 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b' (length=42)
//1 => string 'MD5 Hash: ab56b4d92b40713acc5af89985d4b786' (length=42)
```

Comment: Sounds like making things excessively complicated.... $lambda is a callback that returns an md5 hash; $closure is a callback that calls the specified callback (in this case, $lambda) and does little more than adds a bit of text as well.... for something like this, it just seems pointless overhead because you could simply do `$result = array_map($lambda, $array);` directly

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you. But just for the sake of understanding whats going on in $closure? specially in $lambda($value)?

Comment: `$result = array_map($closure, $array);` calls the callback `$closure` for each element in the array, `$closure` in turn calls the callback `$lambda`, `$lambda` for its part returns the md5 hash of the element value, which `$closure` than adds a bit of text to before returning it as the modified element value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readable translated version hope it helps in understanding lambdas ( php anonymous function ) and closures ( anonymous function with access to variables ) better.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

```
<?php
    $array = array(12345, 'abcde');
    // Returns a value's md5.
    function getNonLambdaMd5( $value )
    {
        return md5($value);
    }

    // Pre-pends 'MD5 Hash: ' text to md5 values.
    function getNonClosureWrapperText( $value )
    {
        return 'MD5 Hash: ' . getNonLambdaMd5( $value );
    }

    // Array_Map replacer to loop through all values within the array.
    $iCountValues = count( $array );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountValues; ++$i )
    {
        // Add each to the result.
        $result[] = getNonClosureWrapperText( $array[ $i ] );
    }

var_dump($result);
//array (size=2)
//0 => string 'MD5 Hash: 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b' (length=42)
//1 => string 'MD5 Hash: ab56b4d92b40713acc5af89985d4b786' (length=42)
?>
```

Comment: Its a very comprehensive example to understand @Vladimir Ramik. Thanks for the example